# What if MBTI differs a lot for short-term and long-term lifestyle?

Tags: personality, decision-making, test, mbti

Regarding the famous MBTI test, I am confused about how stable are the four indicators?

As of my experience, most people are certain whether they are introverted or extroverted. For the other three indicators, however, for some people it differs a lot for short-term and long-term actions. For example, I know a lot of people who are:

- Extremely **XNFP** for short-time actions (e.g. what to do for tonight). They procrastinate a lot and do stuff based on their feelings.
- but at the same time are extremely conservative and **XSTJ** for important life decisions (e.g. choosing a career, finding a research topic, etc.). Their such decisions are almost accurate and based on logical reasoning.

How could we effectively use MBTI interpretations for such people?

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/13627/can-mbti-be-measured-objectively  and https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/13460/what-correlation-research-has-been-done-on-mbti-vs-big5

Comment: A change in habits and lifestyle can indicate another result. However this is a questionnaire based test, anyone will evolve over time. As will the results. Stick to the core personality and the results will be adequate to precisely accurate reflect traits.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure this says all that much about personality. Different cognitive styles in the same individual, depending on the problem, is rather universal see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_process_theory and/or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisficing

Comment: I'm closing this question as not based in psychology.  As noted in the questions linked in comments, the [MBTI tag](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/tags/mbti/info), and [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Briggs_Type_Indicator), MBTI is not a validated instrument, and generally considered pseudoscience.  The lack of reliability noted in the question is potentialy one of several failings of the instrument, which is why it has been superseded by the Big 5.